# Customer address shows "no allow country"

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

When I want to add a new Magento 2.3.3 client in admin, the countries that I have configured do not appear to me.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Allowed countries config is under 
Stores -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Country Options -> Allow Countries

After you make the change, make sure you clear the config cache.

```
bin/magento cache:flush config
```